# Why does \StrBehind{\luatexbanner}{This is} return an empty string?

Tags: expansion, strings, xstring

`\luatexbanner` prints following string:
`This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)`.

However, I want to strip off `This is`.

I have tried `\StrBehind{\luatexbanner}{This is }` using the package `xstring`.

However, it returns only an empty string. My second try was

```
\StrExpand[10]{\luatexbanner}{\mystring}\mystring\\
\StrBehind{\mystring}{This is }
```

But no change here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\luatexbanner` generates a string with category code 12 characters (spaces still are category code 10).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\StrBehind{\luatexbanner}{\detokenize{This is }}[\mybanner]

\begin{document}

\texttt{\mybanner}

\end{document}
```

With `\detokenize` also `This is` will consist of characters with category code 12.

[image]

It's a common policy in the TeX world that all strings generated in such a way have characters with category code 12, except for spaces that remain category code 10. So are the strings generated by

```
\the
\meaning
```

in classical TeX; the ones added by e-TeX, PDFTeX, LuaTeX and XeTeX follow the same patterns. This is in order to ensure predictable results; on the other hand, this makes sometimes harder doing comparisons like in your case. With `\detokenize`, e-TeX introduced a good way to “stringify” tokens.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this was an easy answer for you. I should understand category codes in tex. the doc of `xstring` has a chapter (3.4) about it.